# Nginx reverse proxy to apache acting up?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I have setup nginx as my main server, and I'm using that to reverse proxy to apache on port :8080
Here is my nginx config file for apache.example.io

```
#
# apache.example.io
# Testing apache + nginx
#

server {
        listen 80; 

        root /var/www/apache-example-io; 
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name apache.example.io www.apache.example.io; 

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }   

        location ~ \.php$ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

And here is my file for apache virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerName apache.example.io
    ServerAlias www.apache.example.io
    ErrorLog /var/www/apache-example-io/errror.log
    DocumentRoot /var/www/apache-example-io/public_html
    <Directory "/var/www/apache-example-io/public_html">
       # Order allow,deny
       # Allow from all
       # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3: 
       # Require all granted
       AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

These work fine if I go to http://apache.example.io/index
But I will get a 403 nginx error if I visit http://apache.example.io/ 
I am not sure how to fix this, error logs for nginx look like the following:

2018/03/14 21:25:24 [error] 24730#0: *6 directory index of "/var/www/" is forbidden, client: 211.*, server: apache.example.io, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "apache.example.io"

Googling them and attempting fixes has proved unfruitful :(

Comment: Who owns /var/www? Who runs nginx?

Comment: How would I check? I believe earlier did modify permissions for them to be accessed by get and root runs nginx i believe (also not sure how to check this D:)

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out because I was simply re-routing certain domains I had that all direct towards my server, I hadnt set up a default route.

I opened

> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

And added this in:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server; 
  return 404;
}
```

This will force any non-specified wildcard domains and alike to simply foward to a 404.
Where I want to add a new domain, I make a new file for it either with nginx (NodeJS application) and foward to that IP, or make an apache virtualhost for PHP content serving.
:)